# `object` class has does not have all magic methods, such as __add__(), but how the magic methods are supported by inheriting `object` class?

Tags: python

In Python, all classes inherit 'object' class. I found that the 'object' class does not have all magic methods.

```py
>>> dir(object)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

`object` class has some binary operations such as `__eq__`, `__lt__`, `__gt__`, but some magic methods, such as **add** and `__mul__`, are not in the list. Although `object` class does not have `__add__` and `__mul__`, we can use the magic method as follows:

```py
class Num(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.n>=other.n) and (self.n<=other.n)
    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.n + other.n

a = Num(10)
b = Num(20)

print(a==b)  # False
print(a+b)  # 30
```

How can we use the magic methods, such as `__add__`, which are not defined in `object` class? I am wondering if it is not related to inheriting `object` class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would `object` need to have those methods? It's not like you'd even be using `object`'s versions if they existed - you'd be using your own overrides.

Comment: Are you thinking "how could `__add__` mean anything if it isn't a method of `object`?" That's not quite the right mental model. Fundamentally, the meaning of the dunder methods is defined by the use the interpreter makes of them (e.g. turning the expression `x + y` into a call to `x.__add__(y)`) This is defined by the language spec - https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names - and not by whether those methods happen to be implemented in `object` or not.

Comment: @slothrop Thanks. I had the wrong mental model for it. I thought all magic methods are defined in `object` class such as abstract methods.